# How to Setup Icecast2 Mountpoints?

Tags: html5-audio, icecast, internet-radio, liquidsoap

I was able to setup my icecast2 server in Ubuntu 16.04 (AWS). I can load the admin in icecast2. My problem is, the documentation of icecast2 isn't clear enough for first timers like me on how to setup the mountpoints which is the very essential element of this streaming server since end-users connects to this mountpoints.

If I want people to stream in an HTML 5 player with a descent html styles (html page) how can I do that? Yes, in the documentation of icecast it says, http://my.stream.com:port/mount-name

mount-name?

is it a physical file that list the audio files you wish to stream?

if my mount-name is "radio", does it mean that I have a file called radio ? (I also see mount-names with .ogg file extensions - WHICH I DON'T WANT TO USE SINCE I'LL BE USING mp3s)

if I want people to listen from a styled web page with HTML 5 player, how can I do that?

I also came across liquidsoap. It is interesting. Do you recommend this to use with Icecast?

Thank you

Comment: Thank you for your help. Since you mentioned about default settings of mount. I uncommented this settings from my icecast.xml file: <mount type="default">
        <public>0</public>
        <intro>/basic-radio.ogg</intro>
        <max-listener-duration>3600</max-listener-duration>
        <authentication type="url">
                <option name="mount_add" value="http://auth.example.org/stream_start.php"/>
        </authentication>
        <http-headers>
                <header name="foo" value="bar" />
        </http-headers>
    </mount>    But still mount list is blank from admin

Answer (score 1):

The mount point is simply the path of your stream.  Icecast servers can have multiple streams at once.  I usually pick out a naming scheme based on content, codec, and bitrate.  For example:

- /main-mp3-256k
- /main-aac-256k
- /main-heaac-24k
- /premium-mp3-256k
- *etc.*

This is effectively the URL of the audio stream itself.  This has absolutely nothing to do with a page for your player.  Your player, you build yourself (or install one of the thousands that are out there) and put on your normal website.

Also, this has nothing to do with audio files.  If you're streaming from files, you can just upload those to your web server or CDN... no need for Icecast.  Icecast is intended for use as a live streaming server, radio-style where everyone hears the same thing at the same time.

> isn't clear enough for first timers like me on how to setup the mountpoints

This is configured in your source client.  Just pick something, and the mountpoint is automatically created when you stream to it.

> I also see mount-names with .ogg file extensions - WHICH I DON'T WANT TO USE SINCE I'LL BE USING mp3s

Ogg is a container format, not a codec.  In any case, the extension is meaningless.  It's there by convention only.  The codec and container is configured in your source client.  You can name your mountpoint whatever you want.

> I also came across liquidsoap. It is interesting. Do you recommend this to use with Icecast?

You can use Liquidsoap if you like.  Personally, I've never been more frustrated with a tool like I have been with Liquidsoap.  Its documentation is poor.  Its creators decided to invent a whole new language for its implementation.  Liquidsoap itself throws errors that are not useful.  Getting it compiled with useful modules is a weekend project.  It's also not necessarily the most stable tool out there.

If you choose to use it, let me know when you get stuck.  I've had many consulting clients due to how hard Liquidsoap is to use.

Comment: so if I have "radio" as my mount-name, where is the stream?  what are the content of that stream? if I want to broadcast a list of mp3s and it is uploaded somewhere in my server, how can I do that?

Comment: If you want to use a list of MP3s, a server like Icecast is the wrong technology. What you want to do instead is encode a continuous stream, which is then sent to that mountpoint. For this, you need a source client.

Comment: and that's where source client like liquidsoap comes in right? I tried couple tutorial for liquidsoap+icecast, but I'm unable to have it work. When I visit the streaming URL it returns a 404 error

Comment: Yes, Liquidsoap is one source client.

Comment: Hi Brad! I'm using liquidsoap now and I'm stuck. I put my .liq file inside /etc/liquidsoap. But when I visit the streaming url at http://server.com:8000/my-mount-name it gives a "404 - The file you requested could not be found" error

Comment: I added a follow up question here (might want to help me as well) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48206078/404-the-file-you-requested-could-not-be-found

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with basics:
http://liveice.sourceforge.net/understanding.html 
That's a great site to just get a basic understanding of how things work in the Icecast context.

Specifically a **mountpoint** is a reference to a *virtual* file that if requested by a client *always* has the most recent data.

Also note that for a mountpoint with default settings you can just connect with the `source-password` and Icecast will create the mountpoint on the fly.

If you need *specific* settings, then you should create a `<mount>` section in the icecast.xml configuration file.

Regarding the naming of a mountpoint. That's mostly for listener clients. There is some incredibly dumb software around that only looks at the "file extension" instead of respecting the content-type.

A **very** important distinction is that the format of the *files* you have is for all intents and purposes completely irrelevant when you choose the codec/container of your Stream. As all source clients reencode audio content by default. (You can disable that in a few, but that's *only* for advanced users with full understanding of implications)

In the end, once you have your stream running it's really just pointing the `<audio>` element at the stream URL. Maybe include a cache-buster in the URL, to avoid web browsers being stupid and trying to cache the stream…

Comment: Thank you for your help. Since you mentioned about default settings of mount. I uncommented this settings from my icecast.xml file: <mount type="default">
        <public>0</public>
        <intro>/basic-radio.ogg</intro>
        <max-listener-duration>3600</max-listener-duration>
        <authentication type="url">
                <option name="mount_add" value="http://auth.example.org/stream_start.php"/>
        </authentication>
        <http-headers>
                <header name="foo" value="bar" />
        </http-headers>
    </mount>    But still mount list is blank from admin

Comment: That just sets default values for any stream that would connect. To show up in the web interface you have to actually run a 'source client' and have it connect to the server. See understanding link. Also, I'd strongly recommend against using those values without understanding. It will make things inaccessible and break other things. It's an example of what's possible, not a recommendation to be blindly applied.