# 404 - The file you requested could not be found

Tags: icecast, liquidsoap

My icecast2 server is running and I can see my admin. My config file is setup also with a normal mount set. My source client is liquidsoap, this is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/liquidsoap
# Log dir
set("log.file.path","/var/log/liquidsoap/basic-radio.log")

jazz = playlist("/var/www/html/stream/audio/mp3/jazz")
popular = playlist.safe("/var/www/html/stream/audio/mp3/popular-music")

radio = fallback(
  [ switch(
  [
  ({ 0h-12h }, jazz),
  ({ 12h01-23h59 }, popular),
  ]),
  jazz])

#radio = random(weights=[1,5],[ jazz, radio ])

# Stream it out
output.icecast(%mp3,
host = "18.221.199.44", port = 8000,
, mount = "ssp-radio",
radio)
```

My .liq file is inside /etc/liquidsoap/, filename is radio.liq

But when I try to load from the browser my streaming at http://someserver.com:8000/ssp-radio an error "404 - The file you requested could not be found! " is returned

I also found these in my error log:

```
[2018-01-10  11:49:21] INFO fserve/fserve_client_create checking for 
file /icecast.png (/etc/icecast2/web/icecast.png)
[2018-01-10  11:49:21] WARN fserve/fserve_client_create req for file 
"/etc/icecast2/web/icecast.png" No such file or directory
[2018-01-10  11:49:23] INFO fserve/fserve_client_create checking for 
file /style.css (/etc/icecast2/web/style.css)
[2018-01-10  17:09:13] INFO fserve/fserve_client_create checking for 
file /style.css (/etc/icecast2/web/style.css)
[2018-01-10  17:22:26] INFO fserve/fserve_client_create checking for 
file /style.css (/etc/icecast2/web/style.css)
[2018-01-10  17:22:28] INFO fserve/fserve_client_create checking for 
file /style.css (/etc/icecast2/web/style.css)
[2018-01-10  18:16:04] INFO sighandler/_sig_die Caught signal 15, 
shutting down...
[2018-01-10  18:16:04] INFO main/main Shutting down
[2018-01-10  18:16:04] INFO fserve/fserve_shutdown file serving stopped
[2018-01-10  18:16:05] INFO slave/_slave_thread shutting down current 
relays
[2018-01-10  18:16:05] INFO slave/_slave_thread Slave thread shutdown 
complete
[2018-01-10  18:16:05] INFO auth/auth_shutdown Auth shutdown
[2018-01-10  18:16:05] INFO yp/yp_shutdown YP thread down
[2018-01-10  18:16:05] INFO stats/stats_shutdown stats thread finished
[2018-01-10  18:16:05] INFO auth/auth_run_thread Authenication thread 
shutting down
```

When I try to load this one: http://some-ip:8000/admin/listclients?mount=/ssp-radio
it says:
    400 - Source does not exist

it's looping and I can't stop the server so I need to exit the terminal

What does this mean? No mountpoint is listed in my admin as well. Please help. Thanks

Update:
This is the output from liquidsoap:

```
2018/01/15 13:08:15 [popular-music:3] Successfully loaded a playlist of 
23 tracks.
2018/01/15 13:08:15 [jazz:3] Prepared 
"/var/www/html/mediafiles/audio/jazz/1-14_Let_Me_Be_The_One.mp3" (RID 
3).
2018/01/15 13:08:15 [tea-media:3] Connecting mount tea-media for 
source@my-server-ip-here...
2018/01/15 13:08:15 [tea-media:2] Connection failed: 403, Forbidden 
(HTTP/1.0)
2018/01/15 13:08:15 [tea-media:3] Will try again in 3.00 sec.
strange error flushing buffer ... 
strange error flushing buffer ... 
2018/01/15 13:08:15 [threads:3] Created thread "wallclock_main" (1 
total).
2018/01/15 13:08:15 [clock.wallclock_main:3] Streaming loop starts, 
synchronized with wallclock.
2018/01/15 13:08:15 [fallback_4970:3] Switch to random_4968.
2018/01/15 13:08:15 [random_4968:3] Switch to jazz.
2018/01/15 13:08:19 [tea-media:3] Connecting mount tea-media for 
source@my-server-ip-here...
2018/01/15 13:08:19 [tea-media:2] Connection failed: 403, Forbidden 
(HTTP/1.0)
2018/01/15 13:08:19 [tea-media:3] Will try again in 3.00 sec.
strange error flushing buffer ... 
strange error flushing buffer ... 
2018/01/15 13:08:23 [tea-media:3] Connecting mount tea-media for 
source@my-server-ip-here...
2018/01/15 13:08:23 [tea-media:2] Connection failed: 403, Forbidden 
(HTTP/1.0)
2018/01/15 13:08:23 [tea-media:3] Will try again in 3.00 sec.
strange error flushing buffer ... 
strange error flushing buffer ... 
2018/01/15 13:08:27 [tea-media:3] Connecting mount tea-media for 
source@my-server-ip-here...
2018/01/15 13:08:27 [tea-media:2] Connection failed: 403, Forbidden
```

(HTTP/1.0)
    2018/01/15 13:08:27 [tea-media:3] Will try again in 3.00 sec.
    strange error flushing buffer .
    ...and so on

Comment: There's not remotely enough information here to solve your problem.  What was the output from Liquidsoap?  Did you verify that a TCP connection was made?  Did you try firing up a packet sniffer to see what was sent over the wire, validating authentication and stream data?

Comment: Hi! I updated my post and added the output from Liquidsoap

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the liquidsoap log, it fails to connect, apparently:

```
2018/01/15 13:08:19 [tea-media:2] Connection failed: 403, Forbidden (HTTP/1.0)
```

So likely you supplied the wrong username or password in liquidsoap, and therefore liquidsoap can't connect to the Icecast server.
Make sure you are using the correct source authentication username (usually `source`) and password (configured in your `icecast.xml` as source password).